# Cannot get access token in React app accessing protected .NET Core API with Azure B2C

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm having issues getting an access token from my React app, trying to access my own .NET Core 3.1 web API. I'm able to login fine and can access the user data, but when I try to get an access token, I get the below error continuously. Would appreciate any help or push in the right direction. Thank you!

> Uncaught (in promise) BrowserAuthError: silent_sso_error: Silent SSO could not be completed - insufficient information was provided. Please provide either a loginHint or sid.

Here's what I have:

1. Set up React app registration (SPA w/ redirect to localhost:3000 using auth code flow)
2. Set up .NET Core web api app registration (Web w/ redirect to localhost:44347)
3. Created two scopes for the web api (read and write)
4. Gave api permission to the spa to the web api scopes

.NET Core 3.1 Web API setup (ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration):

1. Startup ConfigureServices

`services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C");`

2. appsettings.json

```
    "AzureAdB2C": {
       "Instance": "https://{example}.b2clogin.com",
       "ClientId": "{web api Client ID}",
       "TenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
       "Audience": "https://{example}.onmicrosoft.com/api"
    }
```

React set up using "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.7.0" and "@azure/msal-react": "^1.0.0-alpha.0" (ref: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-react):

1. index.tsx

```
const configuration: Configuration = {
  auth: {
      clientId: '{SPA Client ID}',
      authority: 'https://{example}.b2clogin.com/{example}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignUpIn',
      knownAuthorities: ['{example}.b2clogin.com'],
  },
  cache: {
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage', // This configures where your cache will be stored
      storeAuthStateInCookie: false // Set this to "true" to save cache in cookies
  }
};
```

`const pca = new PublicClientApplication(configuration);`

```
<MsalProvider instance={pca}>
   <App />
</MsalProvider>
```

2. App.tsx

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
        login(InteractionType.Popup);
    }
  }, [error, login]);
```

3. Accessing the token code

```
const { instance, accounts, inProgress } = useMsal();

useEffect(() => {
        if (inProgress === 'none' && accounts.length > 0) {
            const request = {
                account: accounts[0],
                scopes: ["https://{example}.onmicrosoft.com/api/scope.read"]
            };
            // Retrieve an access token
            instance.acquireTokenSilent(request)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log('response', response);
                    if (response.accessToken) {
                        console.log('accessToken', response.accessToken);
                        return response.accessToken;
                    }
                    return null;
                })
                .catch(error => console.log('token error', error));
        }
    }, [inProgress, accounts, instance]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is having a similar issue, the work around is to pass in the login request with scopes in the initial login. In my case, I'm using useMsalAuthentication() hook to log in. You can follow the thread here, https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2702.

```
export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: [ "openid", "https://{example}.onmicrosoft.com/api/scope.read" ]
}

const {login, error} = useMsalAuthentication(InteractionType.Redirect, loginRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

The documents that you referred are all about Azure AD, but not Azure AD B2C.

We use [`react-azure-adb2c`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-azure-adb2c) library to use ReactJS with Azure AD B2C. You could follow this [blog](https://medium.com/@fiqriismail/how-to-secure-your-reactjs-frontend-with-azure-ad-b2c-8fd165f602e8), and it shows you the steps and sample code.

Comment: Thank you. I would prefer using officially supported libraries, but I'll take a look and see if this could work.

Comment: Hi, @Andrew.Stack.Overflow. I'm afraid there is no official library for integrating azure b2c with react, but you can use MSAL.js to integrate Azure AD B2C with your application, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-b2c-overview). For more information, see this [simple](https://github.com/sunilbandla/react-msal-sample) and the official [MSAL Azure AD B2C sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js).

Comment: The AzureAD team is also building a library to use specifically for React in the same repo you posted. It's what I'm using in my example. https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-react