# ADB2C and MSAL with separate signup and signin policies causing issues

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to use ADB2C custom policies with the MSAL.js library on a static web app

Our policies are reasonably complex, so we've split the 'signup' into it's own flow, but now I'm having trouble with the handover from signup to signin. From what I'm reading it sounds like each IEF policy assigns its own tokens, and so a token generated from a signup flow cannot be used to signin?  Even if they're both associated with the same ADB2C tenant?

Is this correct? It seems odd if so, as the keys (behind the discovery document/jwks_uri) are identical on both policies, as is the issuer.

The error that msal reports is during an 'acquireTokenFromNetworkStart' request which returns a 400 Bad Request `Silent SSO could not be completed - insufficient information was provided. Please provide either a loginHint or sid.`

So perhaps I just need to adjust the session management on the ADB2C policies? Do I need to emit the sid (session id) and then use that with msal when re-acquiring tokens?

Any advice would be most welcome, I cannot find a well documented example that puts all of this together.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if it can be worked around like below .

Try to include your `scope` in the initial loginRedirect or loginPopup or while calling acquireTokenRedirect or acquireTokenPopup before calling acquireTokenSilent.

Scopes that is created in expose an api like "user.read", "mail.send"  in your login request in code and `grant consent` for the same .
That means we need to Call acquireTokenSilent with your resource scope.

```
var loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["openid","user.read", "mail.send"] 
};
try {
    msalInstance.loginRedirect(loginRequest);
} catch (err) {
    // handle error
}
```

In B2C ,your tenant will need to be configured to return the emails claim on idTokens .[Reference](https://In%20B2C%20scenarios%20your%20B2C%20tenant%20will%20need%20to%20be%20configured%20to%20return%20the%20emails%20claim%20on%20idTokens)

Also try to include application Id or app id uri in the scopes .

**References:**

1. [microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2315#issuecomment-706382855)
2. [cannot-get-access-token-in-react-app/SO Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65163347/cannot-get-access-token-in-react-app-accessing-protected-net-core-api-with-azur)